# Count Distinctly Using Window Function

Tags: sql, postgresql

**I want to carry out the count of movies that fall into a particular quartile(1,2,3 or 4) in a particular movie category(animation,children etc)**

My query here displays the category of the movies, the quartile(s) and the count. But I'd love to just pull distinctly, each count for each quartile in their respective category.

Here is my query.

```
WITH t1 AS (
SELECT f.title, c.name, f.rental_duration
FROM film f
JOIN film_category fc
ON fc.film_id=f.film_id
JOIN category c
ON c.category_id=fc.category_id
WHERE c.name IN ('Animation', 'Children', 'Classics', 'Comedy', 'Family', 'Music')), 

t2 AS (
SELECT t1.name,  NTILE(4) OVER(ORDER BY t1.rental_duration) AS standard_quartile
FROM t1)

SELECT t2.name, t2.standard_quartile, COUNT(t2.name) OVER (PARTITION BY standard_quartile ORDER BY t2.name)
FROM t2
```

The resulting table should look like this.

[image: HOW THE RESULT TABLE SHOULD LOOL LIKE]

Comment: I have removed those conflicting dbms tags. Put one of them back, the one for the dbms actually used. (Note that the answers will be different depending on the product used.)

Comment: Expected result is fine, but matching sample table data is also needed. Besides, most people here want formatted text, not images.

Comment: Thank You! @jarlh. How do I go about that?

Comment: Editing tips: https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help.

Comment: Ok. I meant how do I go about matching my sample data. So I get a table like the one in the image?

Comment: [mcve] is a good start.